# How to make a function that will test if my tic tac toe AI is perfect?

Tags: c#, optimization, recursion, artificial-intelligence, greedy

Given each board state, my A.I. will return 1 exact place to move.

I also made a function that loops though all possible plays made with the A.I.

So it's a recursive function that lets the A.I. make a move for a given board, then lets the other play make all possible moves and calls the recursive function in it self with a new board for each possible move.

I do this for when the A.I goes first, and when the other one goes first... and add these together. I end up with 418 possible wins and 115 possible ties, and 0 possible loses.

But now my problem is, how do I maximize the amount of wins? I need to compare this statistic to something, but I can't figure out what to compare it to.

Comment: The only winning move is not to play.

Comment: What you need is a backtracker.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your board? 3x3?

Answer (score 0):

You can treat this as an optimisation problem with an unknown optimum solution. You can then use some form of [meta-heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matheuristics) algorithm (e.g. [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm), [PSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimisation)) to apply variations to your AI until you find the optimum. The interesting thing is that these algorithms might not necessarily return 'the best', but it's still useful to get something better than what you had before.

Usually meta-heuristic algorithms require a fitness function, which basically compares solutions to find the best one. In your case, you can use the win-draw ratio as a fitness function. Having already achieved a 418/115 ratio, you can use this as your 'baseline' in order to compare future solutions.

Unfortunately, I understand what I'm proposing might be too far-fetched (you might be looking for something much more simple), or it might be too general.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure about any statistic that you can use to see if it's perfect. One idea that I just quickly had is to make the assumption that:
- A perfect play only leads to a win or draw.

Your recursive algorithm already returns this. Now the question is, is it possible to increase the amount of wins? Then, you can make the assumption that:
- If both players play perfectly, the result will always be a draw (a cat's game).

Based on this assumption and together with the evaluation of the previous assumption, it means that if your AI (let's call it Bob) is perfect, in a game of Bob vs Bob, the result must always be a draw.

I realise that this still does not help you increase the number of wins (if that's possible), but it provides another metric you can use - to at least ensure that in a Bob vs Bob game, there isn't an edge case where there is a winner (which would mean your AI isn't perfect).